# How to transfer data from my form 2 to form 1

Tags: c#, winforms

Im making a little game that runs in real time. After you enter your name time starts it counts in seconds then minutes then hours. So i have it set up so that when they lets say you click on a button and it takes them to another form. In that form there are some buttons and depending on which one they press it SHOULD send a value back (number of hours) and add it to the current running time in form one automatically, when the form becomes visible again. I have a back button on form2 and i wanted it to add it after you click press it if thats possible!?

Comment: Pass reference to first form to second form, call method on first form from click event in second form. (Or you can directly hook form2.button.Click += form1.Clicked and do the work there)

Comment: Previously answered by me here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636598/creating-multiple-form-gui/19259986#19259986

Answer (score 0):

General the solution for passing data between forms is using events.
- Declare an event in form 2
- when declare form 2 in form 1 subscribe to event
- on event implementation make any operation that you want.

On other solution is to use a design pattern like Producer-Consumer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use events as suggested by ctescu. Another option, if you can show the subforms as dialogs is simply to use the ShowDialog() method instead of the Show() method. This way you can in a simple manner get the propertyvalues after it has been closed.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmSomeForm frm = new frmSomeForm();
        frm.ShowDialog(this);

        if (frm.DialogResult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //When the form is closed we can retrive values from it                                   
            int timeAdd = frm.UserSelection;                

            //Add number of hours to our property/field            
        }

        //We are finished with the form -- dispose it
        frm.Dispose();           
    }
```

All you need to add in the click-event of the "back-button" in the child form is setting the dialog result (When this property is set, the form will close)

```
private void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;            
    }
```