# c# richtextbox search with 2 forms

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, multiple-forms

I've build an email app in c# winforms with a richtextbox.
Now I want to add a search option, which opens in a new Window to enter the search/replace text.
I know how to do this in one form, but how do i get access to the richtextbox in form1 from the second form?

Comment: The most common way is to pass instances of the forms to each other, especially in a constructor.   Then you can access the components you need.  Some more context/actual code (or at least designs) would help improve your quesiton.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating Multiple Form GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636598/creating-multiple-form-gui)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, to have a form return values, one must give it public properties, and have them set by the form when closing.

A more in-depth explanation and examples can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233502/how-to-return-a-value-from-a-form-in-c)